# How to make "Navigator" my default mapping app?

Tags: default-applications, google-maps-navigation

Right now if I click a maps link my phone asks if I want to open in

- Dolphin
- Google Maps (Standard/classic interface)
- Web

I prefer using the Google "[Navigation](http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1650296)" application for its features, such as  voice guidance and input.

How do I get "Navigation" to appear in the list of available apps, or even better make it the default for any map link I click?

Comment: When it asks you to chose, isn't there a checkbox below the question labeled something like "always use this app for actions like this"? If so, simply check it, and then tap the entry for the app you always want to use. This makes it a "default application".

Comment: The navigation not showing in the list is a bigger problem. Is there a kind of "navigate to" button easily clickable in the Google Maps app after you opened it? I'd assume that is how Google wanted it to be done. What Google wants might not equal what you want though

Comment: Izzy the problem is Navigation isn't showing in the list of selectable apps.  There *is* an icon for it on my desktop, and I use it all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `Google Maps` as default and then you only need to select `Navigation` to open `Google Navigation`.

Comment: Right. The extra step is required because [Navigation answers to a different Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5801684/1068283).